# ngAnimate angular for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

i'm trying to use some animations using ngAnimate. In my view i use some ngClass/ngShow etc.. and with ngAnimate can't "live together". ngAnimate breaks the other animations. So, according to the official guide of angular, i tried to disable globally the animations in this way in my controller:

```
$animate.enabled(false);
```

but some components that i use needs of ngAnimate! So i tried to set the animations for certain elements from the controller in this way:

```
$animate.enabled(true, "#my-element-id");
```

but it's not working. Am i wrong?

Comment: Depending on the version you're using, the order of parameters can be reversed: `$animate.enabled([element], [enabled]);`. By the way, try `angular.element("#my-element-id")` instead of a simple string.

Comment: do you mean: $animate.enabled(true, angular.element("#my-element-id"));?

Comment: by the way i tried and i also tried inverting the parameters but still not working.. i can't understand how it works honestly :/

Comment: Which angular.js version you are using?